# How to add a number of weeks to an NSDate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I have in the past used the below function to add on a specific time interval using `NSDateComponents` to an existing date.

```
(NSDate *)dateByAddingComponents:(NSDateComponents *)comps
                          toDate:(NSDate *)date
                         options:(NSCalendarOptions)opts
```

From iOS8 the week value is deprecated for `NSDateComponents`, which means I can't achieve what I want to do: generate a new `NSDate` by adding a certain number of weeks to a given `NSDate`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `weekOfYear`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update: As Zaph said in his answer, Apple actually recommends using `weekOfYear` or `weekOfMonth` instead of the answer I provided. View Zaph's answer for details.

---

You'll probably quickly realize that you're overthinking it, but here's how you can add a certain number of weeks to a date even though the week value's been deprecated, ex:

```
NSDateComponents *comp = [NSDateComponents new];
int numberOfDaysInAWeek = 7;
int weeks = 3; // <-- this example adds 3 weeks
comp.day = weeks * numberOfDaysInAWeek;

NSDate *date = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:comp toDate:date options:0];
```

Comment: No problem. It happens :)

Comment: Sorry but this answer has the potential to be wrong since it assumes every week has exactly 7 days. The answer by @Zaph is safer.

Comment: @rmaddy No need to apologize. I didn't know of any cases when weeks don't have exactly 7 days (daylight savings perhaps?), nor did I realize there was a weekOfYear or weekOfMonth property; but if Apple says to use weekOfYear or weekOfMonth instead, that's what should be used. I'll research this a bit more to figure out the difference between weekOfYear and weekOfMonth then update accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: @LyndseyScott Admittedly I don't know an exact situation where using "days * 7" will give a different result than using "weekOfYear" but daylights savings and leap year (or leap seconds) come to mind.

Comment: When using `weekOfMonth` or `weekOfYear` to add or subtract from a date they work the same. Where they are different is when they are used to obtain the week number. –

Answer (score 18):

Just use `weekOfYear`:

Apple docs for `NSDateComponents` `week`:

> Deprecation Statement
>   Use weekOfYear or weekOfMonth instead, depending on what you intend.

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *comp = [NSDateComponents new];
comp.weekOfYear = 3;
NSDate *date1 = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:comp toDate:date options:0];
NSLog(@"date:  %@", date);
NSLog(@"date1: %@", date1);
```

Output:

```
     
date:  2015-01-13 04:06:26 +0000  
date1: 2015-02-03 04:06:26 +0000
```

If you use `week` you get this warning:

> 'week' is deprecated: first deprecated in ... - Use weekOfMonth or weekOfYear, depending on which you mean

When using the `weekOfMonth` or `weekOfYear` as a delta they work the same. Where they are different is when they are used to obtain the week number where you will get the week of the month with a range of 6 or the week of the year with a range of 53.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use dateByAddingUnit.  It's more intuitive

```
return [NSDate[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitMonth value:3 toDate:toDate options:0];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add a category on NSDate with the following method:

```
- (NSDate *) addWeeks:(NSInteger)weeks
{
    NSCalendar *gregorian=[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    NSDateComponents *components=[[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    components.day = weeks * 7;

    return [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:self options:0];
}
```

Comment: There was a reason Apple removed `week`, don't add it back to `NSDate` in another form when all that is needed is to use `weekOfYear` as the docs suggest.